# Regex to capture the c langage comment use python

Tags: python, regex

This is my regular expression:

> `(//\s*.*)|(?s)(/\*(\s*(.*?)\s*)\*/)`

I test it in http://regex101.com/r/yJ0oA6 website use below text.And as you can see everything is fine.But when type in python code I can not capture the target string.

#### Python excerpt

```
regex_1 = r'(//\s*.*)|(?sm)(/\*(\s*(.*?)\s*)\*/)'
pattern = re.compile(regex_1)
print re.findall(pattern,content)
```

#### Output

```
[('// The variable counter, which is about to be defined, is going\n// to start with a value of 0, which is zero.\nvar counter = 0;\n// Now, we are going to loop, hold on to your hat.\nwhile (counter < 100 /* counter is less than one hundred */)\n/* Every time we loop, we INCREMENT the value of counter,\n   Seriously, we just add one to it. */\n  counter++;\n// And then, we are done.\n', '', '', '')]
```

It should be match six comment lines,but only return the above result,Why? Does I miss something?

Comment: Are you at all concerned that /* */ can appear inside string literals?  If yes, you should use a real lexical analyzer.

Comment: How are you using it in python code?

Comment: I only paste part code about regular expression. @ExplosionPills

Comment: It doesn't matter.I only need to count the comment lines in c source file.But above code can not return collect result.：（ @dstromberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't recommend using regular expressions for doing that, but if you know what you're doing, the following regex will work for you:

```
regex_1 = r'(//[^\n]+)|(/\*.+?\*/)'
```

I cleaned yours a little bit. It will basically match either:

- `//` until the end of the line
- `/* <anything here> */` (non-greedy, of course).

The second case needs to handle multiple lines, and you can do that by specifying the `re.DOTALL` flag when calling `re.compile`:

```
pattern = re.compile(regex_1, re.DOTALL)
```

Below is the output:

```
('// The variable counter, which is about to be defined, is going', '')
('// to start with a value of 0, which is zero.', '')
('// Now, we are going to loop, hold on to your hat.', '')
('', '/* counter is less than one hundred */')
('', '/* Every time we loop, we INCREMENT the value of counter,\n   Seriously, we just add one to it. */')
('// And then, we are done.', '')
```

which is exactly what you're looking for in your example.

Comment: Thanks! Your regex is more better.Simple and more readability

Answer (score 0):

This is due to what I'd say is a bug in python.  From http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

> Flavors that can't apply modifiers to only part of the regex treat a modifiers in the middle of the regex as an error. Python is an exception to this. In Python, putting a modifier in the middle of the regex affects the whole regex.

So unfortunately you can't use `(?sm)`.  Instead, you can use `[\s\S]` to match newlines:

```
(//\s*.*)|(/\*(\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*)\*/)
```

I might point out that `\s*.*` is wrong since this would allow a newline after `//` which would be invalid.  I think it should just be `//.*`.  It is also important to note that this will find comments inside of string literals too, so you have to be careful.

Comment: Thks.It works too.Comments appear inside string literals really exist,but violate c syntax. the best solution is `//[^\n]+`